# Delay function in Pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I'm developing simple game where player scores point and when he/she score certain number of points program print message on the screen and quits. I would like to delay program so user can read the message before program closes, I have tried pygame.time.delay but what it does, it delays screen for a moment and then prints message and in the same moment quits the program. How can I first blit a message, delay and then close the game?

My code:

```
if player.points == 10:
    pygame.time.delay(2500)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, white,[30,500,500,90])
    won_message = font.render("You have won, congratulations!!!", True, black)
    screen.blit(won_message, [150, 535])
```

Comment: Why are you putting the `delay` at the start of the block?

Comment: you kind of said it yourself: print the message first, delay, then close

Comment: Sorry my bad, I have already placed it at the end and was trying other way round. I works the same way, no matter where it is

Comment: Do you update the display before delaying?

Comment: add the line `screen.flip()`

Comment: `time.delay()` stops other functions too - so 
you will not be able to read keyboard or mouse, or make animations at the same time :)

Answer (score 2):

Try doing a [`pygame.display.flip`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.flip) before the delay to force the screen update:

```
if player.points == 10:
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, white,[30,500,500,90])
    won_message = font.render("You have won, congratulations!!!", True, black)
    screen.blit(won_message, [150, 535])
    screen.flip() # if screen is your display
    pygame.time.delay(2500)
```